# python2.7 tsfresh: ImportError: cannot import name defaults

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7

I got the error likes

```py
   import tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators as ts_feature_calculators
  File "/Users/wxy/venv/lib/python3.6/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tsfresh/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tsfresh.convenience.relevant_extraction import extract_relevant_features
  File "/Users/wxy/venv/lib/python3.6/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tsfresh/convenience/relevant_extraction.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tsfresh.feature_extraction import extract_features
  File "/Users/wxy/venv/lib/python3.6/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tsfresh.feature_extraction.extraction import extract_features
  File "/Users/wxy/venv/lib/python3.6/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tsfresh/feature_extraction/extraction.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tsfresh import defaults
ImportError: cannot import name defaults
```

How should I fix this ?

Comment: [tsfresh ImportError: cannot import name defaults #463](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/issues/463)

Comment: Python 2.7 is retired and no longer maintained. Many major packages no longer support python 2.7.